# unity 2d: which better program for making sprites?

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator, gimp, unity-game-engine

### I am beginner to unity 2D  and I  wondering which better program  to make my character sprites

---

shloud i use #photoshop# or illustrator or another program

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop works well if you have the money. Gimp is free and has a surprising amount of features. I've used it for years, and it hasn't had any major limitations, especially for something simple like sprites and backgrounds.

**EDIT**

I should note that if you're interested in the 2D Animation V2 package
(https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.animation@2.0/manual/index.html)
you'll need to export your files as a .psb, not psd. Currently, I don't believe that gimp supports this format.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter. You need png so use program that can export png images.

Comment: okay, thanks @czater

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop is good, you can also have a look at inkscape (vector graphics). It's opensource and free so you keep anything you make (also exports PNG).

I've been using Inkscape for unity 2D and haven't had any issues with it.